# Applying filter to jinja2 template before rendering to LaTeX data

Tags: python, latex, jinja2

I would like to apply a filter to data before it is rendered by jinja into data to be read by a LaTeX generator, for context, this is the problem:

I have a python function `safe_tex`:

```
def safe_tex(text: str) -> str:
    special_chars = ['&', '%', '$', '_', '{', '}', '#']
    for char in special_chars:
        text = text.replace(char, "\\" + char)
    return text
```

What this does effectively is escape any of the defined characters so that when it is rendered and then put into LaTeX, I can use the special characters as regular strings.

Currently I have been able to do this in the template by using jinja's filter function as follows:

```
\begin{document}

Company:    {{company.name|safe_tex}}

\end{document}
```

Which gets rendered to:

```
\begin{document}

Company:    AT\\&T

\end{document}
```

This works just fine for if the company name is AT&T for example (as I need to escape the '&' character for LaTeX to produce the right document) but how can I do this from within my Python environment to avoid having to do it every time in the template?

(The LaTeX templates can reach thousands of lines, hence, I want to avoid having to apply the filter every single place one of the special characters might occur)

Thanks very much in advance :)

Josh